# don't understand specific line of code in UniswapV2Pair.sol, swap function: "amount0In"

Tags: solidity, uniswap

For those familiarized with the code in `UniswapV2Pair.sol`, I don't understand the following line:

```
uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0
```

Observing previous lines, I understand that the amount of the pool "_reserve0" is used to extract the quantity "amount0Out", so the final balance of token0 in the pair pool is,

```
balance0 = _reserve0 - amount0Out
```

Therefore, I don't understand why balance0 is going to be greater than `_reserve0 - amount0Out`.

I attach here previous lines of the code,

```
function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external lock {
    require(amount0Out > 0 || amount1Out > 0, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
    (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
    require(amount0Out < _reserve0 && amount1Out < _reserve1, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');

    uint balance0;
    uint balance1;
    { // scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors
    address _token0 = token0;
    address _token1 = token1;
    require(to != _token0 && to != _token1, 'UniswapV2: INVALID_TO');
    if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (data.length > 0) IUniswapV2Callee(to).uniswapV2Call(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
    balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
    balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
    }
    uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0;
...
```

Comment: _I don't understand why balance0 is going to be greater than_ because you can't sell something you don't have

Comment: exactly like nulik said, but you can also check this post and accepted answer.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102355/understanding-the-swap-function-in-pancakeswap-pair-contract

Comment: Thank you both for the answers, they help. But probably I am missing an important concept, because I see the following flow of the contract:
1. get the balances of the pool before the swap (reserves)
2. transfer out amountOut from the pool (so the new balance is = reserve-out)
3. query the pool balance after that transferout via IERC20 interface, which is going to be: balance = reserve - amountOut, so I don't know why to query
4. if you calculate from here the inflow  amountIn = balance - (reserve-amountOut) = (reserve - amountOut) - (reserve - amountOut) = 0

So.. what am I missing?

Comment: maybe the magic is that this function "swap" is called AFTER the user transfer-in the amountIn. So, the user transfer-in to the pool the "amountIn" she wants to sell, and then the "swap" function is invoked, so now "balance" and "reserve" are not the same. the balance is reserve + amountIn and then after the transfer-out amountOut, the balance is = reserve + amountIn - amountOut [1], so now we are in condition to calculate amountIn directly finding from [1], that is: amountIn = balance-reserve+amountOut = balance - (reserve - amountOut)

Comment: ok, this fact is confirmed in testing: UniswapV2Pair.spec.ts

Answer (score 1):

After finding the solution, that is confirmed in test file `UniswapV2Pair.spec.ts`, I self-answer the question just in case someone is also interested on it. The magic seems to be that this function `swap` is called AFTER the user transfer-in the `amountIn`. So, the user transfer-in to the pool the `amountIn` she wants to sell, and then the `swap` function is invoked, so now `balance` and `reserve` are not the same (otherwise the final calculation of `amountIn` would be zero, as explained in previous comments). The balance after the transfer-in is `reserve + amountIn` (and the fees), and then after the transfer-out `amountOut`, the balance is = `reserve + amountIn - amountOut` [1] (and the fees), so now we are in condition to calculate `amountIn` directly finding from [1], that is: `amountIn = balance-reserve+amountOut = balance - (reserve - amountOut)`